# Count is not being stored in variable in MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am getting very weird issue in MySQL trigger.

Count value is not being stored into variable. Below is my code.

```
DECLARE user_cnt INTEGER;
DECLARE company_id INTEGER;
... 
SELECT IF(COUNT(id) > 0, COUNT(id), -1) INTO @user_cnt
FROM user 
WHERE user_type = 'admin' AND `status` = 'enabled' AND company_id = @company_id;
```

Whereas `@company_id` has a valid integer value.

Here `@user_cnt` is always returning `-1` as value.

What can be done? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you get records for your conditions?

Comment: @juergend, if not specifying company_id condition that it return return count. But when giving company_id condition it does not. For shake of value I am also storing value of `@company_id` into one table to make sure that I am getting value in `@company_id` variable and it does.

Comment: Problem is in you variable name `company_id` which gets matched with your table column during querying that's why you are not getting any value  when you use company_id filter. change your variable to something different like `temp_company_id`

Comment: @AbhishekGinani, still no luck. I changed it with `temp_company_id` but not getting count.

Comment: Provide some sample data . also do you have any value in @company_id?

Comment: @AbhishekGinani 22499 is a value in `@company_id`

Comment: can you test this query outside of your trigger : SELECT IF(COUNT(id) > 0, COUNT(id), -1) 
FROM user 
WHERE user_type = 'admin' AND `status` = 'enabled' AND company_id = 22499; and show as the result

Comment: `company_id` and `@company_id` (`user_cnt` and `@user_cnt`) is different variable !